# Warning in .: Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sqlebc_a08_2.MAI' (Errcode: 13 &quot;Permission denied&quot;)

Tags: php, warnings

[image: This is what in the bottom.]Good evening. I just wanted to ask if does anyone knows what is going on with my database ? I really can't figure it out it causes me headache. I really need help, your answer is so much appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the bottom of the window?

Comment: I added it above, kindly check. Thank you.